# Question about : RNA interference - small-interference RNA AND about Rab-protein in vesicles

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins, protein-binding

First Question :
RNA interference - small-interference RNA

in the textbook -Essential cell biology By Bruce Alberts, Dennis Bray, Karen Hopkin
this Figure is Shown
[image]

my **question** is : if the foreign RNA is **double stranded** and the Dicer Cleaves it so it is still double stranded and **Risc Forming with single stranded RNA** ,i feel there is step missing here ? and how siRNA is finding those complementary RNA when they are in the cell in double-strand ? steps are missing or it is not essential or i myself miss somthing ?

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour]. Note that you should only ask one question at a time. This is two quite distinct questions and needs to be split in half, deleted, and reposted. The second thing is that questions should be about specific problems in biology, rather than a help service for interpreting textbook diagrams. So you need to focus on the point at issue — Where does GTP hydrolysis take place in  *nameofprocess" — and then show that you have checked another text (NCBI Bookshelf has the other Cell Biology book — Lodish) to try to solve the problem.

Comment: @cisco_guy if you are still looking for resources, Wikipedia has a [similar diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA-induced_silencing_complex#/media/File:Part_of_the_RNA_interference_pathway_focusing_on_RISC.png) outlining the formation of the RISC complex, with a step showing the degrading of the passenger strand. I recommend you read the rest of the Wiki and its references